# how to search everything

Tags: search

We have a Wordpress intranet using BuddyPress, bbPress etc..

From [this article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-advanced-search-form-in-wordpress-for-custom-post-types/), I adjusted my theme's `searchform.php` to include:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="docs" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="events" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="forums" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="posts" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="pages" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="topics" />
```

However, when we search for content written inside a Wordpress page, the search does not find this content.

This fact makes me wonder if the search is working properly or not.

The search results page reaches a URL like:

```
www.example.com/?post_type%5B%5D=docs&post_type%5B%5D=events&post_type%5B%5D=forums&post_type%5B%5D=posts&post_type%5B%5D=pages&post_type%5B%5D=topics&post_type%5B%5D=doc&s=document
```

I have tried including singular and plural but the issue remains:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="docs" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="events" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="forums" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="posts" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="pages" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="topics" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="doc" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="event" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="forum" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="post" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="page" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="topic" />
```

Confused.

Help appreciated.

**Update:**

If I add

```
add_action( 'admin_footer', function() { print_r( get_post_types( [ 'exclude_from_search' => true ] ) ); } );
```

to `functions.php`, I receive the output:

```
Array
(
    [revision] => revision
    [nav_menu_item] => nav_menu_item
    [custom_css] => custom_css
    [customize_changeset] => customize_changeset
    [wp_router_page] => wp_router_page
    [forum] => forum
    [topic] => topic
    [reply] => reply
    [buddydrive-file] => buddydrive-file
    [buddydrive-folder] => buddydrive-folder
    [bp-email] => bp-email
    [bp_docs_folder] => bp_docs_folder
    [vc_grid_item] => vc_grid_item
    [bwg_gallery] => bwg_gallery
    [bwg_album] => bwg_album
    [bwg_tag] => bwg_tag
    [bwg_share] => bwg_share
    [tribe_venue] => tribe_venue
    [tribe_organizer] => tribe_organizer
    [deleted_event] => deleted_event
    [rtmedia_album] => rtmedia_album
    [thrive] => thrive
)
```

Comment: `post` and `page` are the built-in post types- singular, not plural.

Comment: Please provide some other code sample of this. So that we can debug better. Only this information is not enough for debugging this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The main search uses `any` custom post types (when you don't set `post_type` query var) so if you're missing *public* custom post types from that, then most likely those custom post types are registered with `exclude_from_search` as *true*.

Check if the plugins have filters to change that or try e.g. to override it with:

```
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', function( $args, $post_type )
{
    if( in_array( $post_type, [ 'foo', 'bar' ], true ) && (bool) $args['public'] )
        $args['exclude_from_search'] = false;

    return $args;
}, 999, 2 );
```

where `foo` and `bar` are some custom post type slug examples that are *public*.

In *bbpress* `forum` and `topic` post types are registered public but with `exclude_from_search` as *true* ([src](https://bbpress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/2.5.12/bbpress.php#L490)). Also note it's *singular* and not `forums` and `topics`.

We can check for *public* and *search excluded* post types with:

```
$types = get_post_types( [ 'exclude_from_search' => true, 'public' => true ] );
```

that might contain an array like this one:

```
Array
(
    [foo] => foo
    [bar] => bar
)
```

Comment: Thanks birgire, I've searched the parent and child themes for `exclude_from_search` and only found one post type called `Option Tree`.

Comment: The custom post types are most likely registered in the plugins. I updated the answer. Check what kind of array `print_r( $types );` gives  @Steve

Comment: I downloaded all plugins, searched the plugins folder for `exclude_from_search` and found the following post types excluded from search: `forum, topic, reply, spam, orphan, hidden status, bwg_gallery, bwg_album, bwg_tag, organizer, venue`. I think this is okay, and should not be preventing me from finding the page content in the original post.

Comment: I created a blank `index.php` with `<?php print_r( $types ); ?>` and it produced an empty white page. :-P Help appreciated.

Comment: Try e..g. `add_action( 'admin_footer', function() {  print_r( get_post_types( [ 'exclude_from_search' => true  ] ) ); } );` in your functions.php file and log in and check the admin footer and play with the parameters. @Steve

Comment: Thanks birgire. See my update to the question please. I don't see returned `page` in the results.

Comment: The post types page and post are searchable by default, but your forum and topic are not. What happens to your search when you use the register_post_type_args snippet above where you replace foo with topic and bar with forum?

Comment: The same symptoms occur. Page content cannot be found by the search. I notice the page content is controlled by WP Bakery Visual Composer. That should not affect the issue should it?